Accessing / downloading artifacts from MLflow running in Docker
I am currently working on a way to implement testcontainers like testing using an MLflow server running in Docker. I use a fairly simple Docker image to setup MLflow server and run a small training script that writes the resulting model as an artifact to MLflow:
# Dockerfile.mlflow-test
FROM ghcr.io/mlflow/mlflow:latest

# Install additional dependencies
RUN pip install scikit-learn pandas numpy

# Set up working directory
WORKDIR /mlflow

# Create MLflow directories
RUN mkdir -p /mlflow/mlruns && \
    chmod -R 777 /mlflow

# Copy and modify training script
COPY train_model.py .

# Train and register model during build
ENV MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=sqlite:///mlflow.db
ENV MLFLOW_ARTIFACT_ROOT=file:///mlflow/mlruns
RUN python train_model.py

# Expose MLflow UI port
EXPOSE 5000

# Start MLflow server
CMD ["mlflow", "server", \
     "--host", "0.0.0.0", \
     "--port", "5000", \
     "--backend-store-uri", "sqlite:///mlflow.db", \
     "--default-artifact-root", "file:///mlflow/mlruns"]

When run, this correctly shows me the MLflow UI and I can also see the artifacts corresponding to the model run (on http://127.0.0.1:5000/#/experiments/0/runs/3894c76664d24c43a537de715a25d664/artifacts).
However, when I then run the following Python code to download the artifacts locally:
import mlflow
from mlflow import MlflowClient
from mlflow.artifacts import download_artifacts, list_artifacts

mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://127.0.0.1:5000")

ARTIFACT_DESTINATION_DIR = "./test-artifacts"
MODEL_NAME = "test_model"
ALIAS = "Test"

client = MlflowClient(mlflow.get_tracking_uri())

def get_latest_version(model_name, mlflow_client=client):
    return mlflow_client.get_registered_model(model_name).latest_versions[0].version

def get_latest_version_for_alias(
    model_name: str, alias: str, mlflow_client=client
) -> int:
    return mlflow_client.get_model_version_by_alias(model_name, alias).version

def get_run_id_for_model_version(
    model_name: str, version: str, mlflow_client=client
) -> str:
    model_version = mlflow_client.get_model_version(model_name, version)
    return model_version.run_id

def download_latest_artifacts_for_model_alias(
    model_name: str = MODEL_NAME,
    alias: str = ALIAS,
    destination_dir: str = ARTIFACT_DESTINATION_DIR,
    mlflow_client=client,
):
    # First, get latest model version for the given alias
    version = get_latest_version_for_alias(
        model_name=model_name, alias=alias, mlflow_client=mlflow_client
    )
    print(f"VERSION: {version}")

    # Get the run ID for this version
    run_id = get_run_id_for_model_version(
        model_name=model_name, version=version, mlflow_client=mlflow_client
    )
    print(f"RUN ID: {run_id}")

    # Construct the artifact URI using runs:/ scheme
    artifact_uri = f"runs:/{run_id}/model"
    print(f"ARTIFACT URI: {artifact_uri}")

    # Define the proper local dir
    full_destination_dir = f"{destination_dir}/{model_name}/{alias}/{version}"

    # Download all of the artifacts
    download_artifacts(artifact_uri=artifact_uri, dst_path=full_destination_dir)

# Test the functions
print("Registered models:", mlflow.search_registered_models())
print("Latest version:", get_latest_version(MODEL_NAME, client))
print("Latest version for alias:", get_latest_version_for_alias(MODEL_NAME, ALIAS, client))
print("Downloading artifacts...")
download_latest_artifacts_for_model_alias(
    MODEL_NAME, 
    ALIAS, 
    destination_dir=ARTIFACT_DESTINATION_DIR, 
    mlflow_client=client
)

I get the following output:
Registered models: [<RegisteredModel: aliases={'Test': '1'}, creation_timestamp=1732547270609, description='', last_updated_timestamp=1732547270696, latest_versions=[<ModelVersion: aliases=[], creation_timestamp=1732547270658, current_stage='Production', description='', last_updated_timestamp=1732547270696, name='test_model', run_id='3894c76664d24c43a537de715a25d664', run_link='', source='/mlflow/mlruns/0/3894c76664d24c43a537de715a25d664/artifacts/model', status='READY', status_message='', tags={}, user_id='', version='1'>], name='test_model', tags={}>]
Latest version: 1
Latest version for alias: 1
Downloading artifacts...
VERSION: 1
RUN ID: 3894c76664d24c43a537de715a25d664
ARTIFACT URI: runs:/3894c76664d24c43a537de715a25d664/model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Projects/my-api/tests/integration/test_container.py", line 154, in <module>
    download_latest_artifacts_for_model_alias(
  File "/home/user/Projects/my-api/tests/integration/test_container.py", line 147, in download_latest_artifacts_for_model_alias
    download_artifacts(artifact_uri=artifact_uri, dst_path=full_destination_dir)
  File "/home/user/Projects/venvs/.my-api/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/artifacts/__init__.py", line 64, in download_artifacts
    return _download_artifact_from_uri(artifact_uri, output_path=dst_path)
  File "/home/user/Projects/venvs/.my-api/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/artifact_utils.py", line 116, in _download_artifact_from_uri
    return repo.download_artifacts(artifact_path=artifact_path, dst_path=output_path)
  File "/home/user/Projects/venvs/.my-api/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/runs_artifact_repo.py", line 131, in download_artifacts
    return self.repo.download_artifacts(artifact_path, dst_path)
  File "/home/user/Projects/venvs/.my-api/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/local_artifact_repo.py", line 85, in download_artifacts
    return super().download_artifacts(artifact_path, dst_path)
  File "/homeuser/Projects/venvs/.my-api/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/artifact_repo.py", line 284, in download_artifacts
    raise MlflowException(
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: The following failures occurred while downloading one or more artifacts from /mlflow/mlruns/0/3894c76664d24c43a537de715a25d664/artifacts:
##### File model #####
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mlflow/mlruns/0/3894c76664d24c43a537de715a25d664/artifacts/model'

I just really don't understand why it can get so far as getting all the metadata, version, run id, etc. but just can't let me download the artifacts? I gather this has something to do with the way the artifacts are "mounted" inside the Docker container file system but I then wonder: how do I properly download artifacts using such local Docker setup?
It's also worth mentioning that I can "just" cURL the artifacts directly using a direct link and run id such as http://localhost:5000/get-artifact?path=model/model.pkl&run_uuid=e6d302306fe446ae92e6ccefcad67167, so it is accessible.
Thank you in advance!
